# checkbox (Icheck) limit not applying to other pages in datatable, only works in the first page

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatables, icheck

The limit in selectable checkbox is only applied on the first page of the table, on the first page, the alert popout when i reached the limit in selectable checkboxes, when I click next page or other page number in the pagination and click another check box, it wont restrict me,  what am i suppose to do that it will also be applied on other pages?

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $datatable = $('#datatable-checkbox');

    $datatable.dataTable({
        'order': [[1, 'asc']]
    });

    var limit = 2;

    $datatable.on('draw.dt', function() {
        $('input').iCheck({
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-green'
        });
    });

    $(".flat").on("ifChecked",function(e) {
        var checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
        var $this = $(this);

        if (checkboxes.filter(":checked").length > limit) { 
            swal({
                title: "Book Limit Reached",
                text: "",
                type: "warning",
            });

            setTimeout(function() {
                $this.iCheck('uncheck');
            }, 1);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use event delegation by providing selector as a second argument in [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) call, see example below:

```
$datatable.on('ifChecked', '.flat', function() {
    // your code here
});
```

From jQuery [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method documentation:

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

See "Direct and delegated events" in jQuery [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method documentation and [jQuery DataTables – Why click event handler does not work](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-why-click-event-handler-does-not-work/) for more information.

Also you need to use [`$()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24()) jQuery DataTable API method to get a list of all checkboxes, because checkboxes for pages other than current will not exist in DOM.

```
var checkboxes = $datatable.DataTable().$("input:checkbox");
```

Comment: thanks for a quick response, but i think i have no idea to construct my code based on your suggestion. ive been trying it but i think im not doing it right :( .. im sorry but can you elaborate more? or if its ok, can you kindly construct the correct code based on my code above?.. it would greatly help me.. thank you

Comment: I get it now, if finally did it.. thank you very much!! frustration got into me first rather than fully understanding it :) hope someone else could be helped from this post.

Comment: when i pass the selected checkbox value from different different page, not all the checkbox were sent during form submit? what should be the possible solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

For reference for others, this is how i did it based on @Gyrocode.com 's suggestion..

btw, i used icheck for checkboxes and sweetalert for popups/alert

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $datatable = $('#datatable-checkbox');

$datatable.dataTable({
    'order': [[1, 'asc']]
});

var limit = 2;

$datatable.on('draw.dt', function() {
    $('input').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-green'
    });
});

$datatable.on('ifChecked', '.flat', function() {
    var checkboxes = $datatable.DataTable().$("input:checkbox");
    var $this = $(this);

    if (checkboxes.filter(":checked").length > limit) { 
        swal({
            title: "",
            text: "",
            type: "warning",
        });

        setTimeout(function() {
            $this.iCheck('uncheck');
        }, 1);
    }
});});
```